# Unable to rotate carousel from bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using Bootstrap and I am attempting to use the carousel example found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)

I have copied the files verbatim minus the two lines it says not to copy. The links are all linking to the correct files.

When I load the page it looks exactly as the example on the bootstrap example but the slides do not rotate and clicking the next/previous buttons do not do anything.

Searching on here I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933992/carousel-images-are-not-rotating-in-bootstrap-css) which is a similar question but the answers are not helpful in this particular example. The problem can be seen [here](http://thumoo.com/create/)

If I look in the console I am presented with the same error three times:

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

which is for the files:

> bootstrap.min.js || holder.min.js || ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js

Any help or suggestions would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Can you check your bootstrap.min.js ? When I open it, I just see HTML, no javascript....

Comment: I have checked the file. In file manager is has the JS icon, opening it with Komodo Edit, it is all formatted as JS correctly. As a side note, I haven't changed any of the javascript files - they are the files as downloaded from bootstrap site.

Comment: I've seen where I went wrong. I completely forgot to change the locations of the JS files. I'm not used to them being at the bottom of the file. Out of sight, out of mind. I've corrected the locations and everything is working fine now. *facepalm*